# how to upload a file in socket io and MongoDB GridFS? (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, websocket, socket.io

I am uploading a local file to MongoDB GridFS

```
    socket.on('/upload',(data)=>{
        console.log(data.file) // <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 01 d4 00 00 02 80 08 06 00 00 00 25 d0 89 10 00 01 31 82 49 44 41 54 78 da ec bd 77 a0 2c c9 55 ... 78217 more bytes>

        fs.createReadStream('./myFile.png').pipe(bucket.openUploadStream('myFile', {
            chunkSizeBytes: 1048576,
            metadata: { field: 'myField', value: 'myValue' }
        }))
    })
```

How to uploading a file sent by a client? (data.file)

socket io will automatically convert the file to Buffer